# Increment Output Display One Less Than Entered

Tags: java

```
package javahistogram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaHistogram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int mark = 0;
        int largest = 0, smallest = 0;
        int rangeOne = 0, rangeTwo = 0, rangeThree = 0, rangeFour = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter marks, -1 to finish: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Process data until the sentinel is entered
        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            {

                while (mark != -1) {
                    mark = in.nextInt();

                    if (mark < -1 || mark > 100) {
                        System.out.println("Error: Enter Valid Input Type: Numbers from 0 - 100 for Marks. Or -1 to finish.");
                    } else if (mark != -1) {
                        sum = sum + mark;
                        count++;

                        if (count == 1) {
                            largest = mark;
                            smallest = mark;
                        } else {
                            if (mark > largest) {
                                largest = mark;
                            }
                            if (mark < smallest) {
                                smallest = mark;
                            }

                            if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
                                rangeOne++;
                            } else if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
                                rangeTwo++;
                            } else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
                                rangeThree++;
                            } else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
                                rangeFour++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Enter Valid Input Type: Integer");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeOne; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeTwo; i++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeThree; i++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeFour; i++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }

        System.out.println(rangeOne + rangeTwo + rangeThree + rangeFour + " students in total");
        System.out.println("Largest mark is: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Smallest mark is: " + smallest);
        if (count > 0) {
            double average = sum / count;
            System.out.println("Average marks: " + average);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeThree; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number of students passed " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

Having an error where my increment doesn't work properly.

For example, if I enter;

```
0, 0, 39, 39, 100
```

5 stars should be displayed.

However, at the moment only 4 stars will be displayed.

I am wondering where in my increment code am I going wrong?

With this, another problem is the format of my program.

For example, in this case of `0,0, 39, 39, 100`
It would display such as:

```
0 - 29: **  
30 - 39: **  
70 - 100: *
```

At the moment, it displays like

```
0 - 29: *  
0 - 29: *  
30 - 39: *  
30 - 39: *  
70 - 100: *
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Please asses the answers and mark the best one as correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your first branch nothing is added. You should change it into checking the largest and smallest value independently of your range counters e.g.

```
if (count == 1) {
    largest = mark;
    smallest = mark;
} else {
    if (mark > largest) {
        largest = mark;
    }
    if (mark < smallest) {
        smallest = mark;
    }
} //Ending bracket is moved here
if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
    rangeOne++;
} else if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
    rangeTwo++;
} else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
    rangeThree++;
} else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
    rangeFour++;
}
```

As for the second part of your question, formatting your output you can use `System.out.print()` to continue printing on the same line, and `\n` to manually break lines. This means to print the name and the stars on the same line you can do like this.

```
System.out.print("0 - 29:");
for (int i = 1; i <= rangeOne; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.print("\n30 - 39:");
for (int i = 1; i <= rangeTwo; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies using `println` in while trying to print the `*`s within your loops.

I recommend using a `do...while` and amending the code slightly:

```
do {
     mark = in.nextInt();
     if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
        rangeOne++;
     } else if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
        rangeTwo++;
     } else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
        rangeThree++;
     } else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
        rangeFour++;
     }
 } while (mark != -1);
```

And the printing loops, use `print`, not `println`.

```
System.out.print("0-29: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeOne; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("30-39: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeTwo; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("40-69: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeThree; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("70-100: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= rangeFour; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

**Note:** you'll have to put in your checks again with this to include any invalid inputs.

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/28CU1V)

Answer (score 0):

problem lies here

```
  if (count == 1) {
                        largest = mark;
                        smallest = mark;
                    } else {
                        if (mark > largest) {
                            largest = mark;
                        }
                        if (mark < smallest) {
                            smallest = mark;
                        }

                        if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
                            rangeOne++;
                        }
```

what it does is it checks for the first number, and if count is 1, it never goes to the else for rangeone++, try taking the logic for smallest and largest out of the counting.